# Counting the number of lines using Python

Tags: python

I am a starter in Python and am getting a line count of a txt file. I have followed exactly as what is given in a online course on Coursera, which is as below:

```
fhand=open("Read Me.txt")
count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count+1
print(count)
```

In the online course this does give the right number of lines, but I keep on getting 0. I guess it may have something to do with the version of the software (mine is Python3.4.3, the online course is Python2), or the text editor of the mac system? Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you are executing the correct script? Also are you sure the file has any lines in it?

Comment: Did you perhaps *already* read the file first and forgot to reopen or seek back to the start? Files, once read, don't start from the beginning automatically on the next read.

Comment: Either MartijnPieters is correct, or there really is nothing in that file.  As a comment, though, you can say `count = len(open("Read Me.txt").readlines())`

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @zondo Thanks! Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all of the code, then your file must be empty.  If there is code that you maybe you thought irrelevant between the `open(...)` call and the `for line in fhand:` loop, it is possible that you read the file and did not seek back to the beginning.  If that is the case, you can do `fhand.seek(0)` to get back to the beginning of the file.  That is not, however, the easiest way to find the number of lines in the file.  You can use `count = len(open("Read Me.txt").readlines())` or `count = len(line for line in open("Read Me.txt"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code 'as-it-is' in your post should work. But if above is just a snippet from your complete code, then you might be reading the file once before this `for` loop. Following example might give you an idea:

```
fhand = open("Read Me.txt")
count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count+1
print(count)

count=0
for line in fhand:
    count=count+1
print(count)
```

Just try adding `fhand.seek(0)` before second `for` loop and the problem will be resolved.

Comment: You are right! I have made some adjustments and now it works. Thanks!